# UIImage slideshow from array

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

Using this Github extension to set image from URL: https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift

I have images stored in a array like this:

```
var userFile = [PFFile]()
```

Images are stored as an URL, and I set the image inside a `UIImageView` like this:

```
imageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string: userFile[indexPath.row].url!)!, placeholder: nil, format: nil, failure: nil, success: nil)
```

How can I display all the images in the same `UIImageView`, but to see the next photo, I have to tap the `UIImageView`?

Comment: do you want them side by side or switching from one after another on tap?

Comment: @EugeneZhenyaGordin - First I want to display the first image, and then switch to the next one tap. No exactly like a "slideshow", but when i tap the `UIImageView`, the image changes to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

This is Obj-c example how to do it. In swift it's very similar.

Add a gesture (tap) recognizer to your image view:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
[self.yourImageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Then on tap:

```
- (void)tapped:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    UIImageView* yourImageView = (UIImageView*)[sender view]; // touch is detected on the imageView

    yourImageView.image = // your image from url
}
```

Swift:

```
// setup gesture recognizer somewhere in the viewDidLoad:

let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))

 yourImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

// this function will be called on tap
func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)
{
    let tappedView = gestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView
    tappedView.image = // add the image needed here
}
```

Comment: What do I put in the "// add the image needed here"?

Comment: whatever you use for the image, in your case: hnk_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string: userFile[indexPath.row].url!)!, placeholder: nil, format: nil, failure: nil, success: nil), right? you're getting it from the URL

Comment: Yes, but I get this error: `Use of unresolved identifier "indexPath"`

Comment: make sure to create a mechanism of getting the next image as you tap on the view, so you're not loading the same image all the time. I can't help you with that, without knowing the internal implementation of how are you getting the images.

Comment: I am getting the image from Parse

Comment: well, I don't see your code...so if you need more help, please post your code, not just one line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110440/discussion-between-eugene-zhenya-gordin-and-roduck-nickes).